# android admob usage

Tags: android, admob

I have made an app for android and have kept the minimum sdk version as 7. But to integrate admob, the minimum sdk version required is 13. I read in one of the questions that to fix this, we can change the target in project.properties to 13 i.e. target=android-13 but this gives a warning `Attribute minSdkVersion (7) is lower than the project target API level (13)`. Could this warning be a reason for the app to be rejected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an app with exactly those settings and that warning in the Android Market. And as far as I know (and see from the amount of 5 star ratings) it doesn't cause any problems.

Answer (score 1):

No, The warning is not a reason to have the app rejected. It is simply a warning that your app may not work on earlier versions of android because of the higher build target.

Comment: Flynn is absolutely right.  The warning is saying, in layman's terms: "Hey, you're app is compiling with android-13, but you are letting your app run on android-7 devices.  Just make sure to test your app on android-7 devices to verify that you aren't using any Android APIs introduced in android-8 or higher.  Otherwise, your app will crash on android-7 devices."

Comment: yes, my own device is running android-7 and it works fine on it. Thanks for the help.